# OpenGL (C Language) : Make the shapes to be moved with keyboard (distortion issue)

Tags: c, opengl, codeblocks, glut

Well, we have the following C (GLUT Project) for OpenGL. I use CodeBlocks to compile it (with removed the extra main() function file).
I have based in some examples, sorry if the way I wrote OpenGL is bad. The main thing is to make it work fine.

The result I need is: all the shapes (head, body, hands, legs) of "Mr Robot", to be moved via the keyboard arrow keys. It works as expected but from some points and then, some of the shapes are distorted. I don't know why and how to fix it.

```
    #include <GL/glut.h>

GLuint kefali_x1=5, kefali_y1=30, kefali_x2=15, kefali_y2=30, kefali_x3=15, kefali_y3=40, kefali_x4=5,kefali_y4=40;
GLuint soma_x1=0, soma_y1=10, soma_x2=20, soma_y2=10, soma_x3=20, soma_y3=30, soma_x4=0, soma_y4=30;
GLuint podia_x1=10, podia_y1=10, podia_x2=20, podia_y2=0, podia_x3=10, podia_y3=-5, podia_x4=0, podia_y4=0;
GLuint dexi_xeri_x1=20, dexi_xeri_y1=30, dexi_xeri_x2=30, dexi_xeri_y2=27.5, dexi_xeri_x3=20, dexi_xeri_y3=25;
GLuint aristero_xeri_x1=-10, aristero_xeri_y1=27.5, aristero_xeri_x2=0, aristero_xeri_y2=30, aristero_xeri_x3=0, aristero_xeri_y3=25;


// σύνθετο σχήμα
GLuint listID;

void MrRobot(GLsizei displayListID)
{
    glNewList(displayListID,GL_COMPILE);

    //Save current colour state
    glPushAttrib(GL_CURRENT_BIT);

    // σώμα
    glColor3f(0.5,0.5,0.5);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(soma_x1,soma_y1);
    glVertex2f(soma_x2,soma_y2);
    glVertex2f(soma_x3,soma_y3);
    glVertex2f(soma_x4,soma_y4);
    glEnd();

    // κεφάλι
    glColor3f(0,0,1);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(kefali_x1,kefali_y1);
    glVertex2f(kefali_x2,kefali_y2);
    glVertex2f(kefali_x3,kefali_y3);
    glVertex2f(kefali_x4,kefali_y4);
    glEnd();

    // πόδια
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex2f(podia_x1,podia_y1);
    glVertex2f(podia_x2,podia_y2);
    glVertex2f(podia_x3,podia_y3);
    glVertex2f(podia_x4,podia_y4);
    glEnd();

    // δεξί χέρι
    glColor3f(0,1,0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2f(dexi_xeri_x1,dexi_xeri_y1);
    glVertex2f(dexi_xeri_x2,dexi_xeri_y2);
    glVertex2f(dexi_xeri_x3,dexi_xeri_y3);
    glEnd();

    // αριστερό χέρι
    glColor3f(0,1,0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2f(aristero_xeri_x1,aristero_xeri_y1);
    glVertex2f(aristero_xeri_x2,aristero_xeri_y2);
    glVertex2f(aristero_xeri_x3,aristero_xeri_y3);
    glEnd();

    //Recall saved colour state
    glPopAttrib();

    glEndList();
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(1,0,0);

    listID=glGenLists(1);

    MrRobot(listID);

    //Execute the display list (the modelview matrix will be applied)
    glCallList(listID);

    glFlush();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key,int x, int y)
{
    printf("\nKeyboard event detected. \nCharacter key: %c\nMouse pointer position: x=%d y=%d",key,x,y);

    if (key==GLUT_KEY_UP)
    {
        kefali_y1++;
        kefali_y2++;
        kefali_y3++;
        kefali_y4++;

        soma_y1++;
        soma_y2++;
        soma_y3++;
        soma_y4++;

        podia_y1++;
        podia_y2++;
        podia_y3++;
        podia_y4++;

        dexi_xeri_y1++;
        dexi_xeri_y2++;
        dexi_xeri_y3++;

        aristero_xeri_y1++;
        aristero_xeri_y2++;
        aristero_xeri_y3++;
    }
    if (key==GLUT_KEY_DOWN)
    {
        kefali_y1--;
        kefali_y2--;
        kefali_y3--;
        kefali_y4--;

        soma_y1--;
        soma_y2--;
        soma_y3--;
        soma_y4--;

        podia_y1--;
        podia_y2--;
        podia_y3--;
        podia_y4--;

        dexi_xeri_y1--;
        dexi_xeri_y2--;
        dexi_xeri_y3--;

        aristero_xeri_y1--;
        aristero_xeri_y2--;
        aristero_xeri_y3--;
    }
    if (key==GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
    {
        kefali_x1--;
        kefali_x2--;
        kefali_x3--;
        kefali_x4--;

        soma_x1--;
        soma_x2--;
        soma_x3--;
        soma_x4--;

        podia_x1--;
        podia_x2--;
        podia_x3--;
        podia_x4--;

        dexi_xeri_x1--;
        dexi_xeri_x2--;
        dexi_xeri_x3--;

        aristero_xeri_x1--;
        aristero_xeri_x2--;
        aristero_xeri_x3--;
    }
    if (key==GLUT_KEY_RIGHT)
    {
        kefali_x1++;
        kefali_x2++;
        kefali_x3++;
        kefali_x4++;

        soma_x1++;
        soma_x2++;
        soma_x3++;
        soma_x4++;

        podia_x1++;
        podia_x2++;
        podia_x3++;
        podia_x4++;

        dexi_xeri_x1++;
        dexi_xeri_x2++;
        dexi_xeri_x3++;

        aristero_xeri_x1++;
        aristero_xeri_x2++;
        aristero_xeri_x3++;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50,50);
    glutInitWindowSize(800,600);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutCreateWindow("MrROBOT");

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    gluOrtho2D(-10,50,-10,50);

    glScalef(0.4,0.4,0.4);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutSpecialFunc(keyboard);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using display lists? I mean, why do you build a display list in the drawing function just to call it in the next step? The purpose of a display list was that you'd fill it with something you'd use again and again, unchanged and could invoke it with a single call. What you do is creating lots of different display lists, changed (and you don't delete the old ones). The display list in your program serves no purpose other than to consume more and more resources. Get rid of it!

Comment: Regarding coding style: You do know what `struct`s are, do you? Also why do you have a ton of variables there, all which get the same alterations applied? You can make this 3 floats and do the rest using the transformation matrices.

Comment: I disagree this question has to be closed as off-topic. No matter how poor the OP's English may be, it is clear that desired behavior is drawing two rectangles, two triangles, one deltoid and moving the shapes across the screen using arrow keys. It is also a clear example of data type mismatch causing UB which breaks drawing routines. One of the answers is also showing how the overall coding of such example programs can be radically improved. As I have not enough privileges to vote against closing, this is the only way for me to express my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have following issues which prevent your program from drawing the desired shapes correctly across the screen:

- declaring and incrementing the vertices as `GLuint` data type
- drawing them as if they were `GLfloat`s, which contradicts the above, causing undefined behavior

Just correct each specification of this type:

```c
glVertex2f(…_xi,…_yi);
```

into

```
glVertex2i(…_xi,…_yi);
```

This should fix the "distortion" problem.

Please, also understand that this answer does not address your coding style, which is not good. SO is not a Tutorial site. See the comments to your post.

Answer (score 1):

> sorry if the way I wrote OpenGL is bad. The main thing is to make it work fine.

Those two usually go hand in hand. If your (OpenGL) code is bad, your program will not work "fine". Write clean code and your program has far better chances to work properly.

So here are a few issues: Why that huge amount of separate (global) variables for xyz? Use structs! Why do you use display lists for immediate drawing? That's not what Display Lists are for, so don't use them! Why do you uniformly alter vertex position values instead of simply changing the transformation?

Clean code structure is all about being able to reason about the program. If there are problems with a program one of the best way to debug is by cleaning up the code; usually all the bad things will become clear as day if you don't fool yourself by thinking "ah, it's just a quick hack"

Isn't this much easier to understand? Also it does work

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

float robot_x = 0, robot_y = 0;

typedef GLfloat vec2[2];

enum { kefali_len = 4 };
vec2 const kefali[kefali_len] = { {5, 30}, {15, 30}, {15, 40}, {5, 40} };

enum { soma_len = 4 };
vec2 const soma[soma_len] = { {0, 10}, {20, 10}, {20, 30}, {0, 30} };

enum { podia_len = 4 };
vec2 const podia[podia_len] = { {10, 10}, {20,  0}, {10, -5}, {0,  0} };

enum { dexi_len = 3 };
vec2 const dexi[dexi_len] = { {20, 30}, {30, 27.5}, {20, 25} };

enum { aristero_len = 3};
vec2 const aristero[aristero_len] = { {-10, 27.5}, {0, 30}, {0, 25} };

static
void draw_vertices2(GLenum mode, vec2 const * const v, size_t n)
{
    size_t i;
    /* use of glBegin + glVertex is outdated since 1997. Whoever teaches
     * is these days should either bring their coursework up to date
     * or consider retirement. */
    glBegin(mode);
    for(i=0; i < n; ++i) {
        glVertex2fv(v[i]);
    }
    glEnd();
}


static
void MrRobot(void)
{
    //Save current colour state
    glPushAttrib(GL_CURRENT_BIT);

    // σώμα
    glColor3f(0.5,0.5,0.5);
    draw_vertices2(GL_POLYGON, soma, soma_len);

    // κεφάλι
    glColor3f(0,0,1);
    draw_vertices2(GL_POLYGON, kefali, kefali_len);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    // πόδια
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    draw_vertices2(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, podia, podia_len);

    // δεξί χέρι
    glColor3f(0,1,0);
    draw_vertices2(GL_TRIANGLES, dexi, dexi_len);

    // αριστερό χέρι
    glColor3f(0,1,0);
    draw_vertices2(GL_TRIANGLES, aristero, aristero_len);

    //Recall saved colour state
    glPopAttrib();
}


static
GLuint generate_display_list_robot(void)
{
    GLuint const list = glGenLists(1);
    if( list ) {
        glNewList(list, GL_COMPILE);
        MrRobot();
        glEndList();
    }
    return list;
}

static GLuint display_list_robot = 0;

static
void display(void)
{
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glViewport(0, 0, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH), glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT) );

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-10,50,-10,50);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glScalef(0.4,0.4,0.4);

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(robot_x, robot_y, 0);
    if( display_list_robot ) {
        glCallList(display_list_robot);
    } else {
        MrRobot();
    }
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

static
void keyboard(int key, int pointer_x, int pointer_y)
{
    fprintf(stderr,
        "\nKeyboard event.\nCharacter: %d\nMouse pointer position: x=%d y=%d",
        (int)key,
        (int)pointer_x,
        (int)pointer_y );

    switch( key ) {
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:    ++robot_y; break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:  --robot_y; break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT: ++robot_x; break;
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:  --robot_x; break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    size_t i;
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50,50);
    glutInitWindowSize(800,600);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutCreateWindow("MrROBOT");

    /* argv[0] is program name */
    for(i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        if( 'd' == argv[i][0] ) {
            if( !display_list_robot ) {
                display_list_robot = generate_display_list_robot();
            }
        }
    }

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutSpecialFunc(keyboard);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```